# Forward foo, reverse bar, but avoid dead code

Tags: code-challenge, kolmogorov-complexity

So simple: Provide some code that outputs `foo` and with the reversed source outputs `bar`. But before you come up with something like [this boring python 2](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69EQSktP19JWakoMUlJoSQvs6jg/38A):

```
print "foo"#"rab" tnirp
```

you should know the **score: You multiply the number of bytes with (1 + dead bytes)**, where dead bytes are bytes that can be changed to most other characters without changing the behaviour in the current execution direction (in the sense that more can be changed than not). This is valid for comments or labels or code after some exit statement or such workarounds (you know what I mean, so don't feel a hero because your language has some feature with a different name to ignore code). I want to see your creativity in reusing code depending on the direction!

**Examples** for score count

- In the example above, the `#` is no dead code, because you cannot simply replace it, but the following 11 bytes are dead code, thus we get a score of 23 * (1+11) = **276**! Valid, but not so nice anymore.
- A [`sh` answer](https://tio.run/##yy7O@P8/NTkjXyEtP19BWaEoMUkhPyM59f9/AA) like `echo foo # rab ohce` would score a slightly better **190**.
- An [`sed` answer](https://tio.run/##K05N0U3PK/3/v9gqziotP9/K2qooMQnILv7/HwA) `s:^:foo:;:rab:^:s` misuses the `:` label to hide code, but the label is still dead code, resulting in a score of **136**.
- `foo//rab` in `///` has the open `//` as valid exit, so this would have only three bytes of dead code, reaching a score of **32**.

**Rules**

- Dead code can be different for both directions, so **for scoring, the number of dead bytes for the worse direction is counted**: If you have three deads bytes forward, but 7 backwards, your multiplier will be 8.
- Your code must not output anything visible after the `foo` or `bar`, just something like whitespaces or newlines.
- `foo` and `bar` can be lowercase or uppercase, as you like
- Your program has to end execution by itself, so don't try to loophole through some infinite loop after output!
- Don't use any non-empty input, of course.
- Why do I add +1 to the dead bytes? Because I don't want a zero score for living-code-only answers like [this `///` solution](https://tio.run/##HYuxCcBADANXyQRSr1nS@CEmRcBg749j3BycDtVn9T7V7REEJZHiPXAEDgyp9YtDKWc5U1zr3AeYdrp/) (actual score 65): 
  `foo/./::://:/\//:f.o.b.a.r::/\// //\/::r.a.b.o.f://\/://:::/./rab`
- Did I mention the **smallest score wins**?

Comment: Please note that [sandbox comments](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/26059/72726) have been resolved.

Comment: Just to clarify - in `print(["foo","bar"][0])`, `,"bar"` is dead code?

Comment: @CommandMaster: `bar` is dead code, because you can replace the characters by most other characters for that direction. The `"` are not dead, because most replacements would break the code.

Comment: In which direction is dead code counted?

Comment: @CommandMaster Good point! I added, that the direction with more dead bytes counts in this case.

Comment: What do you mean by "most other characters"?

Comment: @Adám: In a binary option, »most« means »more than the other option«, so taken literally, there would be more possible replacement characters without changed behaviour than replacement characters that will change it. But as written in the sandbox comment on the identical question, it's not about giving an exact definition of »most«, but about understanding the idea of the task. If someone doesn't understand it, it's recommended not to participate in the challenge.

Comment: Does it have to be all lowercase?

Comment: @Yousername Case doesn't matter. Added.

Comment: Dear close-voters and downvoters: In the sandbox, this challenge has received three upvotes after clarification. If there are still some things unclear, there is the possibility to ask for clarification; I did answer immediately (even though giving a definition of »most« may seem superfluous). Voting to close without commenting on why is not good for the site.

Comment: @Philippos You're right. Even if almost every answer is braindead simple, there's still potential.

Comment: I don't understand what does "Did I mention the smallest code wins?". Do you mean the lowest score wins? Or do you mean that highest score wind?

Comment: @Fmbalbuena It says »smallest *score*«, not »smallest *code*«. You could also say *lowest* instead, same meaning.

Comment: I still do not understand what is intended by "most other characters".  What is the total pool of characters? Why are we changing a *byte* to a *character*? This bit is not worded well.

Comment: @WheatWizard Because different languages have different symbol sets. In a language with only five possible symbols, we can consider it dead code if three characters can be used, while in some language with 256 symbols, even in productive code, three alternatives could be possible.

Comment: @WheatWizard Does this explanation address your question? Do you think this explanation needs to be included into the question?

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn't even realize that was intended to answer the question, I thought it was just a tangential comment.  I still have the questions "What is a character?" "What is the total pool of characters available to replace a character?"

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 8 bytes, score 32

```
bar←←oof
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8psehR2wQgys9P@/8fAA) Outputs `foo`. Explanation: The first word is overprinted in reverse by the reversed second word. The second `←` is needed to overprint and the first `←` is needed to overprint in the correct location, but the first word can be e.g. any three ASCII characters.

```
foo←←rab
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8tP/9R2wQgKkpM@v8fAA) Outputs `bar`.

Answer (score 3):

## Vyxal 3, <s>11 * 6 = 66</s>, 10 * 5 = 50

```
"rab""foo"
```

[Forwards](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyIiLCIiLCJcInJhYlwiXCJmb29cIiIsIiIsIiIsIjMuNC4wIl0=)

```
"oof""bar"
```

[Backwards](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyIiLCIiLCJcInJhYlwiXCJmb29cIiIsIiIsIiIsIjMuNC4wIl0=)

Comment: `"rab""foo"` seems to work

Comment: I'd argue the score is 40 since `"`s aren't dead bytes, changing them mostly result in different outputs.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please add a link to an online tool for verification?

Comment: @Philippos This solution felt kind of trivial, so I didn't put it, but you asked, so here you go!